# Unable to Receive Fcm Push notifications when my app is killed by Battery saver App

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am using `Fcm Push notifications` in my app to notify users. But when app is killed by `Battery saver Apps` or `Cleaning apps` the notifications got skipped and I am not getting any of that notifications after opening my app manually.

How can I **restart** that `Fcm Push notification service` after stopped by any battery saver or cleaning apps?

Comment: Battery saver apps and Cleaning apps are completely useless in Android... so it is right that who is using them can have problems with apps.

Comment: Simple. You can not. It will not work until the user opens your app again

Comment: If we keep both WIFI and cellular data on, mobile switches between them itself. Often it doesn't get notifications until we bring the application front.
So try with using any one of the networks. This may help!